# Flutter Android oAuth with user certificate caching

Tags: android, flutter, webview, oauth, chrome-custom-tabs

Current State:
I am implementing oAuth Authentication for a flutter app running android and iOS.
For iOS my Authentication process works perfectly. I want to get the user prompted for his user certificate every login. Therefore I pass the parameter prompt=login when getting the authCode.

On Android the certificate is getting cached in the browser, so the authentication is triggered without selecting a certificate again. Even when sending the prompt=login parameter.

I have used a couple of libraries.

- flutter_appauth
- flutter inappwebview
- oauth2

The main problem is that when I use a webview the browser doesnt bring up the cert picker.
When I use e.g. custom chrome tab like in appauth there is no possibility to clear the custom tabs cache or chromes cache on logout.
When I use system browser like in oauth2 library I have also no control over the cache.
I have also tried implementing java code to access the cookiemanager to clear cache, but this also only accesses webviews.

I have experienced when I kill the browser app after logout the cache is getting deleted and I get prompted again.

Any solution on how I can clear the cache on custom chrome tabs, system browser or implement the webview that it brings up the cert picker?